# c++/Java in android, dumpReferenceTables to logcat

Tags: android, debugging, java-native-interface

I've had success making a Java app which dumps the JNI locals and globals to the logcat, problem is it only seems to work  for the currently running process.  That code was,

```
        Class cls = Class.forName("android.os.Debug");
        Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod("dumpReferenceTables");
        Constructor con = cls.getDeclaredConstructor();
        con.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(con.newInstance());
```

Our app is in C#, is there any way to call this from Xamarin.Android or Forms?

I also compiled a linux-gnueabi-g++ binary from this or similar code, but am getting runtime errors with env, GetEnv() and an "undefined reference to `JNI_CreateJavaVM'".

```
jclass vm_class = env->FindClass("dalvik/system/VMDebug");
jmethodID dump_mid = env->GetStaticMethodID( vm_class, "dumpReferenceTables", "()V" );
env->CallStaticVoidMethod( vm_class, dump_mid )
```

We have mostly rooted devices so running a c-binary is an option, but am unsure whether this is the proper route at all?  Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't even need JNI for this. `dumpReferenceTables` is public static in `android.os.Debug`. It's marked `@hide`, but should be able to call it through reflection.

Answer (score 1):

Android JNI implementation does not allow `JNI_CreateJavaVM()`, but even if you could create yet another JVM… what references would you dump? Here, each app runs in its separate JVM. So, running a c-binary won't help to look into the running apps.

With root permissions, you can inject your code into any (or all) running apps. The easiest way would probably be to replace the system zygote with your modified version.

---

The C# version of this Java code would probably use [JNIEnv](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Runtime.JNIEnv/), as demoed [here](https://przemekraciborski.eu/2018/03/24/xamarin-android-bindings-fails-lets-hack-into-jni-world).

```
IntPtr cls = JNIEnv.FindClass("android.os.Debug");
IntPtr methodID = JNIEnv.GetStaticMethodID("dumpReferenceTables", "()V");
JNIEnv.CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, methodID);
```

Comment: What if we just try to call the method through C# code?  any leads on that? we are stumped.